# How to use if condition in javascript with respect to json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following json file.

```
{
    "home_page_boolean":true,
    "syllabus_page_boolean":true,
    "schedule_page_boolean":true,
    "hws_page_boolean":true,
    "project_page_boolean":true,
    "banner_school_image_file":"",
    "left_footer_image_file":"",
    "right_footer_image_file":""
}
```

I'm trying to check wether one of the booleans is true or false. Notice that the way I have it now is that the value for the booleans is a boolean value and not a string value, (its not "project_page_boolean":"true")

This is what I tried,

```
if(data.homePageBoolean === true){
    navbar+= "<a id='home_link' class='open_nav' href='index.html'>Home</a>";
}
```

and

```
if(data.homePageBoolean.toString() === "true"){
    navbar+= "<a id='home_link' class='open_nav' href='index.html'>Home</a>";
}
```

but It doesn't work. I'm pretty sure the solution is simple but I can't figure it out

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? What error do you get?

Comment: is `homePageBoolean` vs `home_page_boolean` a typo or in purpose?

Comment: Ha.. how did I miss that

Comment: @aletzo haha! yep that was the problem....good catch

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(data['home_page_boolean']){
    navbar+= "<a id='home_link' class='open_nav' href='index.html'>Home</a>";
}
```

Comment: `if(data['home_page_boolean'])` is preferred. It's messy to equate booleans to booleans in boolean evaluations

Comment: @KyleBecker Even more preferred would be `if (data.home_page_boolean)`

Comment: Any string is considered to be true, that won't work. The way you access the data, as an array entry or with a dot also does not matter.

Comment: @Chris An empty string won't be considered as true. And yes either dot or bracket can be used.

Comment: @Chris What makes you think they're comparing against a string? `data.home_page_boolean` is a boolean value.

Comment: @MikeC It is thinking like that that fills up that bug board

Comment: @Chris What do you mean? It's verifiably a boolean value. Treat it as such. If it's a string then they got bad data and it should have been caught earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as follows :

```
if(data.home_page_boolean === true){
    navbar+= "<a id='home_link' class='open_nav' href='index.html'>Home</a>";
}
```

Comment: home_page_boolean